# Vagrantfile created user password

Tags: ssh, vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows

I have an user created in VagrantFile and whenever I run a command with sudo it asks for a password. I don't  know what that password is, so I would appreciate some help on this matter

I have tried to set up the following without success:

```
config.ssh.username = "Sorin"
config.ssh.password = "6282"
config.ssh.insert_key = false

User created as following in Vagrantfile:
bootstrap = <<SCRIPT
useradd -m Sorin --groups sudo
su -c "printf 'cd /home/Sorin\nsudo su Sorin' >> .bash_profile" -s /bin/sh vagrant
SCRIPT`
config.vm.box = "centos/7"
config.vm.hostname = "centos7"
VAGRANT_COMMAND = ARGV[0]
if VAGRANT_COMMAND == "ssh"
config.ssh.username = "Sorin"
end
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "#{bootstrap}", privileged: true
end

Sorin@centos7 ~  $ sudo yum install whois
```

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

```
#1) Respect the privacy of others.
#2) Think before you type.
#3) With great power comes great responsibility.
```

[sudo] password for Sorin:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it myself by reconnecting to user Vagrant which doesn't  require any password to run as root.

Then I ran the following commands to:

1. `# passwd Sorin` to change the user password for Sorin:
2. `# Visudo` to access and edit etc/sudoers:
   `## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands

   ## %wheel        ALL=(ALL)       ALL`

The ''#" did not exist on my end to remove it. Remove it if exists on your end on the second line in front of %wheel

3. Save changes and return to editor.

4.`# usermod -aG wheel Sorin` to  Add the user I created to the wheel group.

5. `# su USERNAME -` to switch to the Sorin user account that I created.
6. `$ groups
   Sorin wheel`
7. `sudo whoami` to check if it was  root,  the first time it asked for password.